# Ball not falling through hole

Tags: animation, mesh, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am making a ball falling in a ping pong fashion animation. The final part of my animation is the ball falling inside a cone. I added the cone mesh, deleted the top face in edit mode and added the "rigid body", passive and friction settings. But the ball doesn't fall inside the cone. Instead it just sits on top of it.
Some help would massively appreciated.
Thank you. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in the rigid body settings of the cone, you should set the Shape to "Mesh".
That will cause the physics simulation to use the actual geometry of the mesh, instead of an approximation of the shape.

Comment: That just worked. Thanks a lot